# A Quick way to replace trailing substring with another in PHP

Tags: php, string, replace, compare, file-extension

Using PHP,I want to compare the extension of two files and if they are not the same, replace extension of one with another's. I know how to do it with multiple lines, But I am wondering if there is any  way to do it with just a few lines?

```
$first_file='/path/to/the/first/';
$second_file='/path/to/the/second/';
$type1 = strtolower(substr(strrchr($first_file,"."),1));
$type2 = strtolower(substr(strrchr($second_file,"."),1));
if($type2=='')
{
     $second_file.=".$type1";
}
else if($type2!==$type1)
{
     $second_file='second_file with its type replaced by the type1';
}
```

thanks

Comment: there are a doze way to do everything in php, i would stick to yours if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pathinfo function to get the necessary information and replace the extension as below:

```
$first_file='path/asdf/rand.txt';
$second_file='path/asdf/random.png';
$info1 = pathinfo($first_file);
$info2 = pathinfo($second_file);    
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);    
if($info2['extension']!==$info1['extension'])
{
     $second_file=  $info2['dirname'].DS.$info2['filename'].'.'.$info1['extension'];
}
```